# Cancelling a callback inside a suspendCancellableCoroutine

Tags: android, callback, kotlin-coroutines, cancellation

I have wrapped a callback in suspendCancellableCoroutine to convert it to a suspend function:

```
suspend fun TextToSpeech.speakAndWait(text: String) : Boolean {
    val uniqueUtteranceId = getUniqueUtteranceId(text)
    speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, uniqueUtteranceId)
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        this.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : JeLisUtteranceProgressListener() {
            override fun onDone(utteranceId: String?) {
                if(utteranceId == uniqueUtteranceId) {
                    Timber.d("word is read, resuming with the next word")
                    continuation.resume(true)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I'm calling this function with the *lifecycleScope coroutine scope of the fragment* and I was assuming that it was cancelled when fragment is destroyed. However, LeakCanary reported that my fragment was leaking because of this listener and I verified with logs that the callback was called even after the coroutine is cancelled.

So it seems that wrapping with suspendCancellableCoroutine instead of suspendCoroutine does not suffice to cancel the callback. I guess I should actively check whether the job is active, but how? I tried `coroutineContext.ensureActive()` and checking `coroutineContext.isActive` inside the callback but IDE gives an error saying that *"suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body"* What else can I do to ensure that it doesn't resume if the job is cancelled?

Comment: You have `continuation.invokeOnCancellation { callback.cancel() }`

Comment: Thanks, that helps! There is no cancel method for my callback, but I tried to remove the listener on cancellation and it worked: `continuation.invokeOnCancellation { this.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(null)
 } ` No more leaks! Thanks again! Would you like to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> LeakCanary reported that my fragment was leaking because of this listener and I verified with logs that the callback was called even after the coroutine is cancelled.

Yes, the underlying async API is unaware of Kotlin coroutines and you have to work with it to explicitly propagate cancellation. Kotlin provides the `invokeOnCancellation` callback specifically for this purpose:

```
return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    this.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : JeLisUtteranceProgressListener() { 
        /* continuation.resume() */ 
    })
    continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
        this.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(null)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove your `JeLisUtteranceProgressListener` regardless of result (success, cancellation or other errors) you can instead use a classic try/finally block:

```
suspend fun TextToSpeech.speakAndWait(text: String) : Boolean {
    val uniqueUtteranceId = getUniqueUtteranceId(text)
    speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, uniqueUtteranceId)
    return try { 
        suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
            this.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : JeLisUtteranceProgressListener() {
                override fun onDone(utteranceId: String?) {
                    if(utteranceId == uniqueUtteranceId) {
                        Timber.d("word is read, resuming with the next word")
                        continuation.resume(true)
                    }
                }
        })
    } finally {
        this.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(null)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, it would be better to remove the listener anyway. But the main problem in the question was to cancel the job right away and prevent the leak of the calling fragment. But I can combine this with the other proposed solution. Thanks!

Comment: @OyaCanlı the thing is since your continuation is in the suspended state it will immediately finish by (re)throwing `CancellationException` and enter `finally` block. You don't really need explicit cancellation listener in this case.

Comment: Aha! I see, you're right! This works as well. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the accepted answer, I recognized that *continuation* object has an ***isActive*** property as well. So alternatively we can check whether coroutine is still active inside the callback before resuming:

```
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        this.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : JeLisUtteranceProgressListener() 
        {
            override fun onDone(utteranceId: String?) {
                if(utteranceId == uniqueUtteranceId) {
                    if (continuation.isActive) {
                        continuation.resume(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
            this.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(null)
        }
    }
```